# SELinux - Is it possible to inherit from a domain?

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

I am extending Android SELinux policies for supporting proprietary system services. In Android the system_app domain is defined for privileged system apps. I would like my proprietary service to have exactly the same permissions as defined in the system_app domain plus some extras. Is it possible to do so without changing the system_app domain definition or duplicating it? Is there some kind of inheritance mechanism for domains in SELinux?

Answer (score 4):

The SELinux policies on Android do not allow for this capability as you require (requires modification). However, if you look at how types are defined, via the keyword *type*, it allows one to define a new type and also assign it attributes. Another keyword, *typeattribute*, allows for the assignment of an attribute to a type post declaration.

For instance:

```
type foo, kitten, dog;
```

Is the same as:

```
type foo, dog;
typeattribute foo, kitten;
```

Note that all the attributes must be declared via the *attribute* keyword:

```
attribute kitten;
attribute dog;
```

You can think of this, as type foo extends kitten and dog. However, *system_app* is a type, not an attribute, and thus cannot be extended.

At one point in time, I wished to do something very similair and tried to make all the types in the base policy application domains go away and make them attributes for this reason. It was ultimatley abandoned:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/58741/

However, by applying that same idiom, you could achieve your desired outcome.